How do I get a Pardot multi-select field to receive data from a form handler?
I want a webform on Drupal to submit via a form handler to Pardot.
My multi-select in Pardot with pre-defined values stays blank with both a multi-select and checkboxes in Drupal, other fields work fine.
The field name on my webform is commercial_services. If I inspect the code on the form, as a multi-select it becomes commercial_services[]. I have tried using both of these as the External Field Name on my form handler, but neither has worked.
If I try using checkboxes instead, then the names become: commercial_services[option1], commercial_services[option2] etc. This confused me because following this tutorial for a similar task I expected the contents of the square brackets to be blank. Instead, each name contains the value within the square brackets, so I wonder if that means I can't accurately add the External Field Name on the form handler?
Within Pardot, I am able to use this field in a regular form (in an iFrame as opposed to using a form handler) with multiselect, and it works no problem. All the values in my webform 100% match their predefined values in Pardot too, so that can't be the issue.

Not sure about the drupal part, but regarding Pardot (MCAE) i've already done this a couple of times and the way to send all information into pardot is to send each value as a "normal" field, repeating the process for each value.
Example:
Pardot Form Handler URL: https://go.pardot.com/123/form1
Fields:
Email - test@pardot.com
commercial_services - option1 + option2
The way to post this via URL is:
https://go.pardot.com/123/form1?email=test@pardot.com&commercial_services=option1&commercial_services=option2
Depending on which plugin you are using for drupal to post the information into Pardot, you'll have to adjust it or change plugin.

Thank you!  This worked for me.  I could not find this anywhere documented on the internet so this is helpful!

Thank you for replying, I'm just back to working on this project again.
Within Drupal, I have to create a handler for my form, which has the completed URL it sends the data to (for the Pardot form handler), then 'Method: POST' and 'Post type: x-www-form-urlencoded'. I can then tick boxes to choose which values I want to send with the handler.
In this context, is 'post via URL' what I am doing, or would that be a different approach?
